# Sagemaker notebook to EMR pyspark using yarn-client instead of livy

Tags: python, pyspark, amazon-emr, amazon-sagemaker

I know there are good tutorials on connecting  Sagemaker notebooks to EMR cluster for running pyspark jobs via the SparkMagic pre-installed kernel, however we want to connect to the cluster using yarn-client mode instead of livy to be able to use libraries  and configs we already have in our Sagemaker instances, the idea is to run pyspark code on huge datasets, get summaries and use the huge amount of python libraries and custom internal libraries we already have in our sagemaker notebooks to do analysis tasks with the summaries, I've been searching but I can only find connection via livy, my question is: can anyone point to an example for that?

Before cloud/AWS we used an internal/custom on-premise setup(both hadoop/spark clusters and jupyter lab) were we worked with that setup, so we know is possible, just don't know how to do it on AWS and EMR/sagemaker. In our on-premises we do something like the following code(written in the notebook)

```
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.master(“yarn-client”).getorCreate(cluster="just cluster name")
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use SparkMagic on IPython kernel and use the %%spark magic to run code against a remote Spark cluster [[Example]](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic/blob/master/examples/Magics%20in%20IPython%20Kernel.ipynb).
- If you are using SageMaker Studio Notebooks, you can easily connect to EMR clusters using the pre-installed SparkMagic Image, DataScience Image or even using a custom image that you can bring (see [Bring your own image section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-notebooks-emr-cluster.html)) using %sm_analytics magic. [Example here](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-emr/blob/main/blog_example_code/smstudio-ds-pyhive-sentiment-analysis.ipynb) shows a DataScience/IPython kernel connecting to an EMR cluster. You can use %%spark magic to run code against a remote Spark cluster.  [Another example here](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-emr/blob/main/blog_example_code/air-quality-predictions.ipynb) shows how you can use SparkMagic/PySpark kernel to connect to EMR to process huge datasets and easily bring back processed data back to SageMaker Studio Notebook to further analyze the data and do ML.

Let me know if the above examples will help address your use case or if yarn-client mode is still required. [Here's a blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/perform-interactive-data-engineering-and-data-science-workflows-from-amazon-sagemaker-studio-notebooks/) that goes into some more detail about how you can simplify connecting to EMR clusters from SageMaker Studio.